# How to fix Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I'm getting this error sometimes. When I remove **var/cache/** and flush cache, Site works fine without error.

Why this error come and how I fix it permanently?

Comment: This error comes when u try to redirct infinte check ur code specailly custom module

Comment: This comes rarely, while my module is checking data every time. How could I found the cause of this error.

Comment: Check your custom module Router.php file code.

Comment: I didn't make Router.php file in my custom module.